# python multithreading with queue running in sequence not in parallel

Tags: python, multithreading, parallel-processing, queue

why this code is not running in parallel, it take 20 seconds to run it, which means it is running in sequence. Thank you for your help.

```
import time
from queue import Queue
from threading import Thread
start = time.time()
def f():
    time.sleep(0.5)
    print("yes")
    return 'yes'


def do_stuff(q):
    while True:
        output = q.get()
        q.task_done()


q = Queue(maxsize=100)
for message_nbr in range(40):
    q.put(f())

num_threads = 10

for i in range(num_threads):
    worker = Thread(target=do_stuff, args=(q, ))
    worker.setDaemon(True)
    worker.start()

q.join()
print("time: ", time.time() - start)  # ~20 seconds
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer lies here:

```
for message_nbr in range(40):
    q.put(f())
```

You're putting 40 instances of None into your queue, because you're calling `f()` which returns None instead of passing `f` (the function object) in. This block is what is taking 20 seconds to run!

Changing this code

```
def do_stuff(q):
    while True:
        output = q.get()
        q.task_done()
```

to this

```
def do_stuff(q):
    while True:
        output = q.get()
        output()
        q.task_done()
```

is also necessary (you need to call the function!)

Final:

```
import time
from queue import Queue
from threading import Thread
start = time.time()
def f():
    time.sleep(0.5)
    print("yes")
    return 'yes'


def do_stuff(q):
    while True:
        output = q.get()
        output()
        q.task_done()


q = Queue(maxsize=100)
for message_nbr in range(40):
    q.put(f)

num_threads = 10

for i in range(num_threads):
    worker = Thread(target=do_stuff, args=(q, ))
    worker.setDaemon(True)
    worker.start()

q.join()
print("time: ", time.time() - start)  # time:  2.183439254760742
```

Answer (score 0):

this one works !

```
start = time.time()
def f(m):
    time.sleep(0.5)
    print("yes")
    return 'yes'


def do_stuff(q):
    while True:
        output = q.get()
        final_result = f(output)
        q.task_done()


q = Queue(maxsize=0)
for message_nbr in range(10):
#     q.put(f())
    q.put(message_nbr)

num_threads = 10

for i in range(num_threads):
    worker = Thread(target=do_stuff, args=(q, ))
    worker.setDaemon(True)
    worker.start()

q.join()
print("time: ", time.time() - start)
```